# NHibernate Entity code conversion from #C to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, nhibernate

Hello and thanks for your help in advance.

I am starting on the NHibernate world and i am experimenting with the NHibernate CookBook 
recipes, i am trying to set a base entity class for my entities and this is the C# code for this. I would like to know whats the VB.NET version so i can implement it in my sample project.

This is the C# code:

```
public abstract class Entity<TId>
{
 public virtual TId Id { get; protected set; }

 public override bool Equals(object obj)
 {
 return Equals(obj as Entity<TId>);
 }

 private static bool IsTransient(Entity<TId> obj)
 {
  return obj != null &&
  Equals(obj.Id, default(TId));
 }

 private Type GetUnproxiedType()
 {
  return GetType();
 }

 public virtual bool Equals(Entity<TId> other)
 {
   if (other == null)
   return false;
   if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
   return true;

   if (!IsTransient(this) && !IsTransient(other) && Equals(Id, other.Id))
   {
    var otherType = other.GetUnproxiedType();
    var thisType = GetUnproxiedType();
    return thisType.IsAssignableFrom(otherType) ||
    otherType.IsAssignableFrom(thisType);
   }
   return false;
 }

 public override int GetHashCode()
 {
   if (Equals(Id, default(TId)))
   return base.GetHashCode();
   return Id.GetHashCode();
 }
}
```

I tried using an online converter but puts a Nothing reference in place of default(TId) that doesn't seem right to me that's why I request for help:

```
 Private Shared Function IsTransient(obj As Entity(Of TId)) As Boolean
        Return obj IsNot Nothing AndAlso Equals(obj.Id, Nothing)
    End Function
```

I Would appreciate the insight you may give me on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question is correct: `Nothing` in VB stands for two things, depending on context: `null` if assigned to or compared with a reference type, and `default(T)` if used in the context of a value type `T`.

Comment: and `default(Object) == null`, so `Nothing` is synonymous with `default`.

Comment: Thanks Konrad for the input. The conversion should work then. I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this as the sample and base your project around this. Please keep me updated about your status if possible. IN general how easy or difficult it was. Getting resources of the web etc.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/nhibervbdotnet.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/NHibernate_VB_Net.aspx

Comment: Thanks user35 for your will to help me. I will keep you and the guys posted on this.

Answer (score 1):

C# and VB have something in common. They use the .NET Framework. Therefore, it is (often) very easy to convert between them, without any errors.

You should take a look at the converter here, and see if it generates your code without nasty errors. Normally, it works like a charm for me! http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Thanks Math, actually this is the converter that I tried. I will look for a different one and see what is its C# output, compare with the other one and test the whole thing again.